# Dynamically calling classes

Tags: php, class, dynamic

```
class App 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "app is now running...\n";
        $this->getModel('Something');
    }

    public function getModel($name)
    {
        return new $this->getModelInstance($name);
    }

    protected function getModelInstance($name)
    {
        return 'Model_' . $name;
    }
}
```

I have autoloader set-up and working. Why can't I load Model_Something this way, but I get the following error in return:

```
Notice: Undefined property: App::$getModelInstance in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ProjectName\app\App.php on line 13

Fatal error: Class name must be a valid object or a string in C:\Apache24\htdocs\ProjectName\app\App.php on line 13
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
public function getModel($name) {
  $modelInstanceName = $this->getModelInstance($name);
  return new $modelInstanceName();
}
```

---
The right way to instantiate a class is :

```
new Classname($parameter);
```

So when you were doing this :

```
new $this->getModelInstance($name);
```

The class' name was :

```
$this->getModelInstance
```

So it was looking for the `getModelInstance` attribute (and not function) in your App class, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I am trying to find the documentation concerning this, I do not want to explain this with wrong words. If someone else can, do not hesitate!

Comment: @caCtus not exactly, it's more as if your were calling `new [whatever string is returned by getModelInstance()]`

Comment: @Félix : Why the `Undefined property: App::$getModelInstance` error and not a `Class 'Model_Something' not found` error then? (Model_Something is the string returned by `getModelInstance()` function here) That is how I understood the issue but maybe I am wrong (and maybe PHP tried to do the best it could in this case).

Comment: just another explanation, what is happening is that it is trying to create an instance for the property `getModelInstance` and `($name)` is try to call that instances constructor. So if there was a `getModelInstance` property with the value `foo`,  you are essentially saying `new foo($name)`. Since the property doesn't exist you are saying `new {null}($name);`. Saving the output to a variable will get you the string as a return which you can call `new $string` with no problem. I tried stuff like wrapping with parens or braces (which usually works) with no luck.

Comment: Also when I tried to solve the problem, I tried `new $this->getModelInstance($name)()`, but syntax error (same with braces). I have to admit I saw the problem, I saw how to solve it but can't explain clearly why, I don't like it. :) Thanks for your help. @Félix @Jonathan

Comment: `new {$this->getModelInstance($name)}()`

Comment: @Félix this doesn't work either, `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{'` , that's why I chose to put the string in a variable before instantiate the class. But yes, it seemed good to me too at first.